# Jquery - Email body - Print encoded URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open email box with some content by clicking button. Am using following code in jquery.

```
window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body='message%20goes%20here'";
```

In Email body its printing as 'message goes here' ... But i want to print as is like 'message%20goes%20here'

Please help me guys.

Comment: You actually use plain JavaScript in this code. There is no jQuery...

Comment: `body='message%2520goes%2520here'`

Comment: yes.. actually i am using this code with jquery button click event. Inside jquery click event , this javascript code will get executed

Comment: thanks a lot @FrédéricHamidi .. u saved my time.. its working.. Can u please let me know, what %2520 will do?

Answer (score 0):

use `encodeURIComponent`

for your code, try this:

```
var messageBody = "message%20goes%20here";
window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body="+encodeURIComponent(messageBody);
```